# Setting INSTALL_RPATH no longer works when I start using a custom toolchain file

Tags: macos, cmake

To make my library target link with another dynamic library I am using the [following commands](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/blob/f74b55caac6a718cafbaaca88e81ca324f4bbf55/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L137):

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "${MyTargetRPaths}")
```

This works perfectly until I introduce a [custom toolchain file](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/blob/f751dc8931966bae8b303b98f2232f8c3ae251b6/Mull.toolchain.OSX.cmake).

I have read [Mac OSX and the RPATH](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling#Mac_OS_X_and_the_RPATH) wiki and tried all possible combinations of settings suggested there (some of their descriptions are quite obscure) and still I am seeing:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libstd-a260b5db713b337f.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Stanislaw/Projects/mull/BuildXcode/unittests/Debug/MullUnitTests
  Reason: image not found
```

`otool -L` command shows me that rpaths to the libraries I need no longer expand to the full paths of these libraries and I see `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` empty.

```
$ otool -L mylib.dylib 
    @rpath/libstd-a260b5db713b337f.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libtest-551a7b69d9c2ff2f.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

I still cannot find how presence of `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$(myfile)` changes the setup of `*RPATH*` settings in CMake.

Comment: Instead of linking to the existed project, please, create [mcve]. As far as I understand, toolchain file can be compressed to two lines (setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` variables). The project could also be compressed to 10-20 lines, where one needn't to search through 100 lines, whether value for *INSTALL_RPATH* is absolute or relative path. Setting variable *CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME* always means **cross-compiling**. Do you perform "fake" cross-compiling, when your *host* is the same as value for *CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME*?

Comment: ZOMG!!! @Tsyvarev, I have just removed `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and **it started working! I was following blindly one of the toolchain osx examples on the internet. Thanks so much for your answer, feel free to write it as an answer and I'll accept it. As of simple examples: I wish I would have one provided, it is just that it is my first experience with CMake and I am doing a refactoring on existing project so I am still can't extract essentials from my understanding.